# Proof explanation - Differentiable and continuous functions in higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem:** Let $E$, $F$ be normed vector spaces. If $f:E\to F$ is differentiable in $x_o \in E$ and $f'(x_0)$ continuous, then $f$ is continuous in $x_0$.

**Proof:** It follows directly from
$$||f(x)-f(x_0)||_F\leq||f(x)-(f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0))||_F+||f'(x_0)(x)-f'(x_0)(x_0)||_F$$

Why so? I personally don't understand where the link between the theorem and the proof is, can someone explain it to me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Typo, edited . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of differentiability, $f$ being differentiable in $x_0$ means that there exists an application $f'(x_0) \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ such that :

$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+o(||h||_E)$$

Then by linearity $f'(x_0)(x-x_0)=f'(x_0)(x)-f'(x_0)(x_0)$, hence :

$$||f(x)-f(x_0)||_F=||f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f'(x_0)(x)-f'(x_0)(x_0)||_F$$

By triangular inequality :

$$||f(x)-f(x_0)||_F\leq||f(x)-(f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0))||_F+||f'(x_0)(x)-f'(x_0)(x_0)||_F$$

Now, we use the definition above, we have that :
$$||f(x)-(f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0))||_F=||f(x_0+(x-x_0))-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)||_F=o(||x-x_0||_E)$$
And also, since $f'(x_0)$ is continuous : 
$$||f'(x_0)(x)-f'(x_0)(x_0)||_F=o(||x-x_0||_E)$$

And we are done. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that :
$||x-x_0||_E<\delta \Rightarrow$
$$||f'(x_0)(x)-f'(x_0)(x_0)||_F \leq \frac \epsilon 2 \text{ and } ||f(x)-(f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0))||_F\leq \frac \epsilon 2$$

Then $$||f(x)-f(x_0)||_F \leq \epsilon$$